# C++ Call to overloaded template func is ambiguous. Compiler doesn't take apart prototype and definition

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, ambiguous

It is such a ridiculous compile error.
I just declare a function template prototype and define it afterwards.
There is no error, its declaration and definition both have the same signature, but compiler considers them as two different function templates.

Compiler:`g++ (Ubuntu 8.1.0-5ubuntu1~16.04) 8.1.0`

Code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

// declaration
template <typename TString, typename TChar>
auto prependToString(TString & string, const TChar * const & cString)
-> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<TChar, std::remove_reference_t<decltype(string[0])> >,
    TString &>;

// definition
template <typename TString, typename TChar>
auto prependToString(TString & string, const TChar * const & cString)
-> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<TChar, std::remove_reference_t<decltype(string[0])> >,
    TString &>{
    string.insert(0, cString);
    return string;
}

int main(){
    std::wstring wideOne;
    const wchar_t * wideCString = L"wide text";
    prependToString(wideOne, wideCString);  // ambiguity complaint

    return 0;
}
```

Compile output:

```
tegeran@Vitaha:~/studing/tests/cpp_test$ g++ main.cpp -std=gnu++2a
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:20:41: error: call of overloaded ‘prependToString(std::__cxx11::wstring&, const wchar_t*&)’ is ambiguous
     prependToString(wideOne, wideCString);
                                         ^
main.cpp:5:6: note: candidate: ‘std::enable_if_t<is_same_v<TChar, typename std::remove_reference<decltype (string[0])>::type>, TString&> prependToString(TString&, const TChar* const&) [with TString = std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t>; TChar = wchar_t; std::enable_if_t<is_same_v<TChar, typename std::remove_reference<decltype (string[0])>::type>, TString&> = std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t>&]’
 auto prependToString(TString & string, const TChar * const & cString)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:6: note: candidate: ‘std::enable_if_t<is_same_v<TChar, typename std::remove_reference<decltype (string[0])>::type>, TString&> prependToString(TString&, const TChar* const&) [with TString = std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t>; TChar = wchar_t; std::enable_if_t<is_same_v<TChar, typename std::remove_reference<decltype (string[0])>::type>, TString&> = std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t>&]’
 auto prependToString(TString & string, const TChar * const & cString)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'ts signature uses SFINAE as I have more overloads for this functuion in my actual code, but they don't seem to cause the trouble.
To mention, compiler version prints `ubuntu1~16.04`, but my current ubuntu version is `18.04`, maybe the clue is here

Comment: Strangely enough, this compiles fine with Clang 6.0.1.

Comment: [It's a compiler bug apparently](https://godbolt.org/g/wnn6Qz).

Comment: Is this the simplest form of the code that will produce the error?

Comment: @r3musn0x This is not so strange really. MSVC gives an almost identical error, now **that** is strange.

Comment: @n.m. Isn't that the norm ;)?

Comment: @Tim hmm, i managed to simplify signature to 

    `template <typename TString>
    auto prependToString(TString & string, const wchar_t * const & cString)
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(string[0]), wchar_t &>,  
    wchar_t> {
        return string[0];
    }`

Comment: @PasserBy It would be, but the error makes no sense whatsoever. Also only the 2015 version (19.00.24210) does; the 2017 version compiles this.

Comment: Btw, as a workaround, `decltype(string[0])` can be replaced with `typename TString::value_type` see https://godbolt.org/g/ozAtft, which I find to be nicer anyways.

Comment: @n.m. for me VS2017 compiles this fine

Comment: [This](https://godbolt.org/g/YX4QA3) is what I've got it reduced to.

Comment: @Frank yeah, but it may lack in generality a bit, however a true workaround would be not to use trailing return type hera at all, idk why I used it in the first place

Comment: @VTT yes, VS2015 has this problem. https://godbolt.org/g/vHcz36

Comment: @PasserBy a different problem apparently, only in trunk. 8.1.0 compiles it.

Comment: @n.m. That's even weirder. Guess we ran into two bugs at once.

Comment: @n.m. it probably is the same issue, 8.1.0 just exhibits it at instantiation instead of compilation: https://godbolt.org/g/BLpf8j

Comment: I think I've [isolated everything](https://godbolt.org/g/m2zzb9). The bug happens when there is a value templated on a `decltype` that depends on the function parameter, and the value is used as a template parameter.

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61370).

Comment: @PasserBy `canonical types differ for identical types`? Is this the same as `call to overloaded f is ambiguous`?

Comment: @SimpliestOne Maybe not, but looks like it. The error message on trunk is the same, and the constructs looks pretty similar. File a bug report if you don't think so.

Comment: @PasserBy okay then, thank you